# Application shows out of Memory Exception and crashed

Tags: android

I have a strange situation in which my application is getting crashed sometime(say after doing nearly 20 transaction).
I have increase my heap memory too using  `android:largeHeap="true"`.

> Logcat

```
 07-20 11:27:39.207: E/AndroidRuntime(17877): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-20 11:27:39.207: E/AndroidRuntime(17877): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
07-20 11:27:39.207: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at java.util.ArrayList.toArray(ArrayList.java:492)
07-20 11:27:39.207: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:93)
07-20 11:27:39.207: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at com.mis.adapter.MicListAdapter.<init>(MicListAdapter.java:52)
07-20 11:27:39.207: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at com.mis.controller.InventoryCount$InflateList.onPostExecute(InventoryCount.java:3061)
07-20 11:27:39.207: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at com.mis.controller.InventoryCount$InflateList.onPostExecute(InventoryCount.java:1)
07-20 11:27:39.207: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
07-20 11:27:39.207: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
07-20 11:27:39.207: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
07-20 11:27:39.207: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-20 11:27:39.207: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-20 11:27:39.207: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
07-20 11:27:39.207: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-20 11:27:39.207: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-20 11:27:39.207: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
07-20 11:27:39.207: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
07-20 11:27:39.207: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here i have attached my `onPostMethod()` and doInbackground()

```
protected void onPostExecute(List<MIC_OrderDetails> lst) {
        dialog.setMessage("Inflating Data...");

        if (lst.get(lst.size() - 1).getResult().contains(("success"))) {
            list.clear();
            ordList.clear();
            list.addAll(lst);

            ordList.notifyDataSetChanged();
            dialog.dismiss();
        } else {
            dialog.dismiss();
            toastText.setText("Problem in loading Items");
            Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 410);
            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setView(toastLayout);
            toast.show();
        }
    }

@Override
        protected List<MIC_OrderDetails> doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String result = "";
            List<MIC_OrderDetails> lst = new ArrayList<MIC_OrderDetails>();
            try {


                lst=handler.getdata(spinLoc);


                result = "success";
                MIC_OrderDetails mic_OrderDetails = new MIC_OrderDetails();
                mic_OrderDetails.setResult(result);
                lst.add(mic_OrderDetails);

            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                result = "error";
                MIC_OrderDetails mic_OrderDetails = new MIC_OrderDetails();
                mic_OrderDetails.setResult(result);
                lst.add(mic_OrderDetails);
                dialog.dismiss();
                Log.e("Failed", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            return lst;
        }
```

> MICListAdapter.java

```
package com.mis.adapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.example.mobinventorysuit.R;
import com.mis.mic.model.MIC_OrderDetails;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;

import android.widget.TextView;

public class MicListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MIC_OrderDetails>  implements Filterable{

    List<MIC_OrderDetails> alllst;
    List<MIC_OrderDetails> list;

    List<MIC_OrderDetails> filterlst;
    // = new ArrayList<MIC_OrderDetails>();
    Context context;

    TextView txtitem;
    TextView txtdesc;
    TextView txtpick;
    TextView txtQtyonHand;
    TextView txtQtyCounted;
    TextView txtuom;
/*  TextView txtstatus;*/

    private ModelFilter filter;

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (filter == null) {
            filter = new ModelFilter();
        }
        return filter;
    }

    public MicListAdapter(Context context, List<MIC_OrderDetails> value) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(context, R.layout.six_textview, value);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = value;
        this.alllst=new ArrayList<MIC_OrderDetails>(list);
        this.filterlst=new ArrayList<MIC_OrderDetails>(alllst);
        getFilter();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final int pos = position;

        View view = null;
        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.six_textview, parent, false);

            txtitem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_fullItemNo);
            txtdesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_fullDesc);
            txtpick = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_fullLoc);
            txtQtyonHand = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_fullord);
            txtQtyCounted = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_fullrecqty);
            txtuom = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_fullUom);
            convertView.setTag(new OrdersViewHolder(txtitem, txtdesc, txtpick,
                    txtQtyonHand, txtQtyCounted, txtuom));


        } else {
            OrdersViewHolder viewHolder = (OrdersViewHolder) convertView
                    .getTag();
        }

        OrdersViewHolder holder = (OrdersViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        holder.txtitem.setText(alllst.get(position).getItemNumber());
        holder.txtdesc.setText(alllst.get(position).getItemDescription());
        holder.txtpick.setText(alllst.get(position).getPickSeq());
        holder.txtQtyonHand.setText((alllst.get(position).getQtyonHand()));
        /*String o=(lst.get(position).getQtyShiped()).toString();
        String u=lst.get(position).getUom();*/
        holder.txtQtyCounted.setText((alllst.get(position).getQtyCount()));
        holder.txtuom.setText(alllst.get(position).getUnit());
    /*  holder.txtstatus.setText(alllst.get(position).getStatus());*/


        return convertView;

    }

    /** Holds child views for one row. */
    static class OrdersViewHolder {

        TextView txtitem;
        TextView txtdesc;
        TextView txtpick;
        TextView txtQtyonHand;
        TextView txtQtyCounted;
        TextView txtuom;
/*      TextView txtstatus;*/

        public OrdersViewHolder(TextView txtitem, TextView txtdesc,
                TextView txtpick, TextView txtQtyonHand, TextView txtQtyCounted,
                TextView txtuom) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.txtitem = txtitem;
            this.txtdesc = txtdesc;
            this.txtpick = txtpick;
            this.txtQtyonHand = txtQtyonHand;
            this.txtQtyCounted = txtQtyCounted;
            this.txtuom = txtuom;
            /*this.txtstatus=txtstatus;*/

        }


        public TextView getTxtitem() {
            return txtitem;
        }

        public void setTxtitem(TextView txtitem) {
            this.txtitem = txtitem;
        }

        public TextView getTxtdesc() {
            return txtdesc;
        }

        public void setTxtdesc(TextView txtdesc) {
            this.txtdesc = txtdesc;
        }



        public TextView getTxtuom() {
            return txtuom;
        }

        public void setTxtuom(TextView txtuom) {
            this.txtuom = txtuom;
        }

        public TextView getTxtpick() {
            return txtpick;
        }

        public void setTxtpick(TextView txtpick) {
            this.txtpick = txtpick;
        }


        public TextView getTxtQtyonHand() {
            return txtQtyonHand;
        }


        public void setTxtQtyonHand(TextView txtQtyonHand) {
            this.txtQtyonHand = txtQtyonHand;
        }


        public TextView getTxtQtyCounted() {
            return txtQtyCounted;
        }


        public void setTxtQtyCounted(TextView txtQtyCounted) {
            this.txtQtyCounted = txtQtyCounted;
        }

        /*public TextView getTxtstatus() {
            return txtstatus;
        }

        public void setTxtstatus(TextView txtshipvia) {
            this.txtstatus = txtshipvia;
        }*/
    }

    private class ModelFilter extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
            if (constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0) {
                ArrayList<MIC_OrderDetails> filteredItems = new ArrayList<MIC_OrderDetails>();

                for (int i = 0, l = alllst.size(); i < l; i++) {
                    MIC_OrderDetails customer = alllst.get(i);
                    String strNum = customer.getItemNumber();//tHhCustomer_number();

                    if (strNum.toLowerCase().contains(constraint))//|| strName.toLowerCase().contains(constraint))
                        filteredItems.add(customer);
                }
                result.count = filteredItems.size();
                result.values = filteredItems;
            } else {
                synchronized (this) {
                    result.values = alllst;//ModelItemsArray;
                    result.count = alllst.size();
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                FilterResults results) {

            filterlst = (ArrayList<MIC_OrderDetails>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            clear();
            for (int i = 0, l = filterlst.size(); i < l; i++)
                add(filterlst.get(i));
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please show MicListAdapter?

Comment: I have edited the question where you can get MicListAdapter class @MichaelSpitsin

Comment: Also could you please provide what happens here com.mis.controller.InventoryCount$InflateList.onPostExecute(InventoryCount.java:3061) and how many items you have in list and MIC_OrderDetails. Thank you.

Comment: Nearly 2200 items available in the List...

Comment: To inflate my Listview i'm running an Asynctask...I'm getting all the items in doinbackground method with on extra value that may be "success" or "error" , which can be passed to the onPostExecute Method

Comment: Are you using the keyword `static` anywhere in your code? Are you loading pictures? I can't tell from skimming through your code, but you are most likely dealing with a memory leak. Memory issues don't just happen. In 99.9% of all cases there is a leak or something similar which causes all available memory to clog up. Setting `android:largeHeap="true"` doesn't fix that.

Comment: yes,i'm using one static variable...

Comment: On Clicking on Listview i'm opening one customized dialog box from where we can update the database(Sqlite) and inflate the Listview in doingbackgroud...If we perform this task nearly 30 times...out of memory exception generated...@MichaelSpitsin

Comment: Show us the part of the code where you use the static variable.